# Allow self-referrals for a Universal Analytics tracker on a subdirectory

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

We have a Universal Analytics implementation that has multiple trackers in use across different sections of a site. There is one 'global' tracker which resides on **all** pages of the site, and then a number of individual trackers on separate Web Properties which are for versions of the site in other languages, which are hosted in subdirectories. i.e.:

www.example.com - has global tracker

www.example.com/fr - has global and /fr trackers

www.example.com/es - has global and /es trackers

and so on...

Each of these /xx subdirectory trackers has its own _ga cookie on a separate path matching the language, so the tracker for .com/es has its cookies on the path '/es' for example.

So with that setup in place we were expecting to see valid self-referral traffic from visitors moving from one subdirectory to another, or from the .com root site into one of these language specific sites. However, we're only seeing these visitors as Direct traffic.

We have removed the root domain from the Referral Exclusion List in the tracking settings for each of these properties, but that doesn't appear to have affected anything at all.

We do want to see traffic moving these directories though, does anyone know how we can get these "legitimate" self-referrals appearing again, or does Universal Analytics cut them out by default? Would I be able to use filters (using the full referral URL field value) or channel groupings to swap this traffic into Referrals or is there another/better way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Cheers.

Comment: How long has it been since you've removed the root domain from the Referral Exclusion List? I've had to wait 24-48hrs for the update to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that those visitors have been already marked as direct traffic, so they are not taken as referrals. Your change may only affect to NEW visitors.